# Bind to DependencyProperty on Custom Class

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having issues binding to a custom class.  The dependencyproperty does not seem to get the correct value from my viewmodel.  Here is my custom class:

```
    public class DataResource : DependencyObject
        {

            public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("Content",
                    typeof(object),
                    typeof(DataResource));

            public object Content
            {
                get { return (object)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
                set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
            }

        }
```

And in my UserControl resources, I have:

```xml
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:DataResource x:Key="dataResource" Content="{Binding Test}"></data:DataResource>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

"Test" in my ViewModel is a property that I can bind a Label to with no issues.  Am I doing something wrong here in this implementation?

Update: This works if I inherit from Freezable instead of DependencyObject. I'm not quite sure why, hopefully somone can explain this.

Answer (score 3):

There is no context in the `Resources`, the `DataResource` would need to be placed somewhere in the `UserControl` so it can inherit the `DataContext` so that the binding (which is relative to the `DataContext` unless a source is defined) is complete.

(A problem with that is that `DependencyObject` don't even have a "real" `DataContext` as that property belongs to `FrameworkElement`, if you are lucky there is an artificial context though)

Comment: If I change my DataResource class to extend from FrameworkElement, do I not have a context still?  I can use a CollectionViewSource within my resources and the binding works fine since my UserControl already has the DataContext set.

Comment: Maybe that works via [inheritance context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickkramer/archive/2006/08/18/705116.aspx), i am not sure though. But changing the type to `FrameworkElement` is certainly *not* the right step to take in any way, in you really cannot bind to the current DataContext you should consider using another source, like `ElementName` or `Source` and specify a path relative to that source.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the FrameworkElement.SetBinding method on the Dependency Property in your code behind. Then you don't need to set the data context for the entire page (since DataContext and DP's don't mix well).

Here is the MSDN on that:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598273.aspx

Sample:

```
MyData myDataObject = new MyData(DateTime.Now);      
Binding myBinding = new Binding("MyDataProperty");
myBinding.Source = myDataObject;
myText.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

Comment: This method is used to circumvent XAML binding. I end up doing this a lot in Silverlight because of binding conflicts or DP's that don't properly trigger onchanged on user controls. It's worth a shot, but must be in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Since content seems to be of type `object` -which leads me to believe that will be used to host a class- , the problem might actually be the
*depth of "listening"*. If a property of `Test` changes (a.k.a. change of a string) you will be notified. If a property of `Test` is an object that doesn't inherit from `DependencyObject` and a property of it gets changed, you will not get notified. The last scenario goes on recursively.

According to [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.freezable?view=net-5.0) :

> [...]
>
> **Detailed change notification**: Unlike other `DependencyObject` objects, a `Freezable` object provides change notifications *when sub-property values change*.
>
> [...]